# Windows 7 .htaccess file name is showing blank

Tags: .htaccess

Before I opened with Notepad, .htaccess files was showing with file extension in folders. Because .htaccess has blank name. After opened with Notepad, file extension was lost.
I deleted all registry about .htaccess in regedit but it does not work.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

How can I set this like the before picture?

Comment: Did you restart your computer after you changed the registry?

Comment: Thanks, it fixed after restart.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your computer for the changes to take effect.